# blank value istead in a mutiply subquery

Tags: sql, sybase, cumulative-sum

I have this SQL in Sybase to get the cumulative value of of a quetity mulitiplied by the price but it gives blank values when I want it to show real values.

Here is my code :

```
    SELECT Pmu.IdVal, Pmu.IdInt, Pmu.IdNumEcrPpal, Pmu.IdSensOpe, Pmu.DtEcr, Pmu.QteEcr, Pmu.PrixAcquis,
    (SELECT SUM(p1.QteEcr)
            FROM   casimir.dbo.Pmu p1
            WHERE  p1.IdNumEcrPpal < Pmu.IdNumEcrPpal and p1.IdInt = Pmu.IdInt) AS QCP,
     (SELECT SUM(p2.QteEcr * p2.PrixAcquis) 
            FROM   casimir.dbo.Pmu p2
            WHERE  p2.IdNumEcrPpal < Pmu.IdNumEcrPpal and p2.IdInt = Pmu.IdInt) AS PRUP 

    FROM casimir.dbo.Pmu Pmu

    where IdInt = 1733

order by IdNumEcrPpal
```

Here is the result:

```
IdVal * IdInt * IdNumEcrPpal *  QteEcr *    PrixAcquis *    QCP PRUP
650     1733    1074292               69    0.00         {null} {null}
650     1733    1165538               6     0.00            69  0.00
650     1733    1618644               7     0.00            75  0.00
650     1733    1934483               10    0.00            82  0.00
650     1733    1934484               1     0.00            92  0.00
650     1733    2140552               93    0.00            93  0.00
650     1733    2506329               200   0.00            186 0.00
650     1733    2515839               100   0.00            386 0.00
650     1733    2520087               110   0.00            486 0.00
650     1733    2572565               400   0.00            596 0.00
650     1733    2581126               1     0.00            996 0.00
650     1733    2858466               56    0.00            997 0.00
650     1733    2907483               6     0.00            1053 0.00
650     1733    3227255               7     0.00            1059 0.00
650     1733    3440560               173   0.00            1066 0.00
650     1733    3440727               67    0.00            1239 0.00
650     1733    3467592               100   0.00            1306 0.00
650     1733    3482135               100   188.00          1406 0.00
650     1733    3483475               30    185.35          1506    
650     1733    3491124               350   0.00            1536    
650     1733    3717502               70    0.00            1886    
650     1733    3717503               4     0.00            1956    
650     1733    4046744               20    65.44           1960    
650     1733    4047669               200   0.00            1980    
650     1733    4059311               150   67.12           2180    
650     1733    4101861               200   0.00            2330    
650     1733    4118371               36    0.00            2530    
650     1733    4118372               3     0.00            2566
```

The column PRUP gives me the right value but give blank values after.

Any idea

Answer (score 0):

I edited my query. Please also refer the link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c48ec/27

```
SELECT Pmu.IdVal, Pmu.IdInt, Pmu.IdNumEcrPpal, Pmu.QteEcr, Pmu.PrixAcquis
   ,
    (SELECT SUM(p1.QteEcr)
            FROM   Pmu p1
            WHERE  p1.IdNumEcrPpal < Pmu.IdNumEcrPpal and p1.IdInt = Pmu.IdInt) AS QCP,

     coalesce ((SELECT SUM( coalesce (p2.QteEcr,0) *  coalesce (p2.PrixAcquis,0)) 
            FROM   Pmu p2
            WHERE  p2.IdNumEcrPpal < Pmu.IdNumEcrPpal and p2.IdInt = Pmu.IdInt),0) AS PRUP

 FROM Pmu Pmu

    where IdInt = 1733

order by IdNumEcrPpal
```

Comment: thank you very much, ifnull where not accepted, tried this instead but still have the same result : coalesce(p2.QteEcr,0) * coalesce(p2.PrixAcquis,0)

Comment: There may be some problem in your where clause. Its not getting any value for PRUP. Try to use coalesce in your select clause. I am just revising my sql.

Comment: I deleted my where clause completely but still the same issue :/

Comment: can u put a sample data in sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: I m doing this but dont know how to giev you access

Comment: first build schema. Then run the sql query. It will change the url. Post the url here

Comment: Thank you very much I think its a problem of my engine, I still face the same issue :/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ISNULL` function

```
SELECT Pmu.IdVal, Pmu.IdInt, Pmu.IdNumEcrPpal, Pmu.IdSensOpe, Pmu.DtEcr, Pmu.QteEcr, Pmu.PrixAcquis,
isnull((SELECT SUM(p1.QteEcr)
        FROM   casimir.dbo.Pmu p1
        WHERE  p1.IdNumEcrPpal < Pmu.IdNumEcrPpal and p1.IdInt = Pmu.IdInt),0) AS QCP,
 isnull((SELECT SUM(isnull(p2.QteEcr,1) * isnull(p2.PrixAcquis,1)) 
        FROM   casimir.dbo.Pmu p2
        WHERE  p2.IdNumEcrPpal < Pmu.IdNumEcrPpal and p2.IdInt = Pmu.IdInt),0) AS PRUP 
FROM casimir.dbo.Pmu Pmu
where IdInt = 1733
order by IdNumEcrPpal
```

You can also use `coalesce` function instead.

Comment: Thank you @Parado but I get blank value same as before

Comment: Thank you but still same result :/

Comment: @user2583029 I have no idea why it doesn't work. Can you show us some data to count first row from your expected result?